# Run jar file in remote computer

Tags: remote-server

I need to run some jar file in another machine in **LAN**.

```
java -jar start.jar
```

How to run a jar file on remote computer?

Thx!

Comment: Connect to that machine via SSH and run it there? Or are you asking how to execute arbitrary code on another computer?

Comment: do you have ssh access to this machine? In this case you just have to connect via ssh and enter the same command

Comment: i have this jar file in the some shared folder on remote computer.. i need to run this jar in remote computer.

Comment: How is this question related to java programming? Nor Delphi. You should at least state what OS you are using.

Comment: java because I need to run jar file.. Delphi because I need to run this jar file from delphi application..

Comment: This is off-topic on StackOverflow, as it has nothing to do with programming (or tools primarily used for programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue in my project while accessing resources in a distributed systems environment. If you working on Windows, you need **PsExec v2.x**.

Create a [batch](http://www.comscigate.com/HW/cs33/CreateJarBatchFile.pdf) file to execute **java -jar start.jar** from remote cmd.

Now run the batch file from ur local machine by `PSEXEC \\othermachine z:\program.exe`. You will need administrator privileges on the target machine.

[Visit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553)  for documentation.

Lastly, if you demand platform independency and wish to run your jar on remote machine having OS other than the OS on your local machine, then you should go with socket programming.

Comment: Thx for your recommandation.. It seems that it is interesting! I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Via remote client like ssh, teamviewer or custom solution with server-client connection.